# can ehcache allow searching with diskstore?

Tags: ehcache

I tried using ehcache but the ehcache fails when I try to save data on disk. Gives

> net.sf.ehcache.config.InvalidConfigurationException: Search attributes
>   not supported by this store type:
>   net.sf.ehcache.store.DiskBackedMemoryStore .

If my memory capacity of 200 Mb is exceeded then i cannot use the ehache in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ehcache search API does (at least currently) not work with disk persisted caches.

Comment: Is there any other cache like jboss cache or infinispan  that allows disk persisting cache so that if memory of RAM exceeds it can be stored in disk?

Comment: You should probably write down a list of specific requirements or a description of the specific problem you are trying to solve and open a new question. There are quite many solutions available, but to recommend one we need to know the problem domain.